# session error ? using POST using requests or urllib2

Tags: python, python-requests

trying to authenticate to a website and fill out a form using `requests` lib

```
import requests
payload = {"name":"someone", "password":"somepass", "submit":"Submit"}

s = requests.Session()
s.post("https://someurl.com", data=payload)

next_payload = {"item1":"something", "item2":"something", "submit":"Submit"}
r = s.post("https://someurl.com", data=next_payload)
print r.text
```

authentication works and i verified that i can post to forms but this one i am having problem with gives `The action could not be completed, perhaps because your session had expired.  Please try again`
Attempted in urllib2 and same result -- dont think its an issue with a cookie. 
I am wondering if javascript on this page has something to do with giving session error? other form page doesnt have any javascripts.

Thanks for your input...

Comment: Does the submit have to be in the payload?  Can you pass the payload directly to the submit action?

Comment: silly me -- yeah you dont need the submit in the payload. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665086/python-requests-login-post-to-asp-page/24665195#24665195


Try this ..