# python requests login/post to asp page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Folks,
  Trying to scrape some data from an internal company site which doesnt provide an api :(

The form on the site takes in a `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, but its action is not 'login', but a link to a CA page, ie `'action': '/something/forms/login.fcc'`

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {
    'action': '/something/forms/login.fcc',
    'USERNAME':'foo',
    'PASSWORD':'bar'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://internal/unprotected/login.asp',headers=headers,data=payload)
x = s.get('https://internal/blah/mainSearch.cfm')
print x.text
```

Gets me back to a login screen...  Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Comment: As I remeber APS send more information for own use. Maybe it needs it during login.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. This is how I fixed it -- see if this works for you ...

```
from requests import Request, Session
session = Session()
post_request = Request('POST', 'https://internal/unprotected/login.asp', headers=headers, data=payload)
prepare_post = session.prepare_request(post_request)
post_response = session.send(prepare_post)

get_request = Request('GET', 'https://internal/blah/mainSearch.cfm')
prepare_get = session.prepare_request(get_request)
get_response = session.send(prepare_get)
```

Comment: `session = Session()` is that a python module?

Comment: should `session = requests.Session()`?

Comment: Yes, it would be `session = requests.Session()` if you import the `requests` module with `import requests`. If you use `from requests import *` then `session = Session()` would work. It should be noted the former is preferred to the latter to avoid namespace issues.

Comment: what is the action in your request? normally you post to url/endpoint with required post args. Is there any csrf involved in this process then you have to retrieve that from get_request and send it as header to post request.